# Regex to parse out values in parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I want to be able to separate a string into values by splitting by spaces, but if something is in parentheses I need it to be in a single value. So for example, `(a b c) d e (f g) h` should become `['a b c', 'd', 'e', 'f g', 'h']`. What's a regex that will do that for me?

Comment: `'(a b c) d e (f g) h'.match(/\([^\)]+\)|\S+/g)` seems to come close for that input. Maybe throw in some capturing groups and use `.exec()` in a loop? Are any parentheses in the input guaranteed to be balanced? And can they be nested?

Comment: @nnnnnn no, I can't guarantee that they are balanced but they are supposed to be, so if they're not balanced it's supposed to throw an error anyway.

Comment: @nnnnnn also no, they can't be nested.

Comment: @nnnnnn to specify, yes they can be nested but that shouldn't affect the output. A nested parenthesis should be treated like any other character

Comment: Based on @nnnnnn 's answer try: `string.match(/\([^\)]+\)|\S+/g).map(x => x.replace(/[\(\)]/g,""))`.

Comment: That's great! Put it into an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: But this doesn't satisfy your condition: "A nested parenthesis should be treated like any other character"

Comment: Dealing with nesting using regex can be difficult or impossible. It would be easier to just use a loop to read the string character-by-character, and keep a count of how deeply nested you are.

Comment: @ammarx hmm, I think it's unreasonable to deal with nesting tbh, I'll just put it in the spec that parentheses can't be nested and if they are then behaviour will be undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, dealing with nesting in regular expressions is impossible, so this is a code that deals with your problem; it uses regular expressions and other techniques:

```js
var str = '(a (b) c) d e (f g) h';
var match;
var myRe = /\([^]+?\)|\S+/g;
var result = [];

while (match = myRe.exec(str)) {
  result.push(match[0]);
}

var tmp = "";
var final = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  var leftP = (result[i].match(/\(/g) || []).length;
  var rightP = (result[i].match(/\)/g) || []).length;
  if (leftP !== rightP) {
    tmp += result[i];
    for (var j = i + 1; j < result.length; j++) {
      tmp += result[j];
      if ((tmp.match(/\(/g) || []).length === (tmp.match(/\)/g) || []).length) {
        final.push(tmp);
        tmp = "";
        i = j + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    final.push(result[i]);
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < final.length; i++) {
  final[i] = final[i].replace(/\)(\S+)/g, ') $1');
}
for (var i = 0; i < final.length; i++) {
  final[i] = final[i].replace(/^\(([^]+)\)$/, '$1');
}
```

It might be not optimized but I think it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right, the standard JavaScript regex engine cannot handle nested patterns. If you use Perl, PHP or .NET you can do it with a pattern like [this](https://regex101.com/r/wlTzPZ/1):

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<open>\()
  (?<close>\))
  (?<val>(?&open)|(\w\s?)+)
  (?<start>(?&open)(?&val)(?&close))
)
(?&start)|(?<=\s)\w
```

It can be done in JavaScript too using an extended JavaScript regular expressions library like [XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp). Here is a sample, to give you the idea:

```
const str1 = '(a b c) d e (f g) h';
var s = XRegExp.matchRecursive(str1, '\\(', '\\)', 'g');
console.log(s);
// -> ['a b c', 'f g']
```